# Can I use one data type to define multiple functions in C?

Tags: c, function

Example:

```
void WriteNos(), ConvertDecInt2Binary(), ConvertDecimal2Binary(), ReadNos(), 
ConvertBinary2DecInt(), ConvertDecFloat2Binary();
```

or do I need to place `void` before  each function? This is basic C only question.

Comment: This is function _declaration_, not function _definition_.

Comment: What did your compiler tell you when you tried?

Comment: There isn't a prototype in that collection of declarations; don't declare functions without prototypes.  That was a necessity before 1989; it ceased to be a necessity before 2000.

Comment: A declaration has a type (formally, a list of declaration-specifiers) and a list of declarators (formally an init-declarator-list-opt).  Each function name with parentheses after it is a declarator.  The code is fine as written — if you ignore the absence of prototypes.  Note that those functions all take an indeterminate list of arguments (but are not variadic functions with `...` at the end of the argument list).

Comment: `gcc` thinks `ReadNos` returns `void`, so, technically it works. But, do _not_ do this! It is _far_ less clear and less readable than spelling things out (e.g. `void WriteNos();` and then [on a separate line] `void ReadNos();`). I've _never_ encountered this construct before. IMO, you're trying to be, um, well "too cute for your own good" ... And, use the ansi prototypes (vs. the old K&R ones) as Jonathan mentioned. Oh, BTW, where would you put comments describing each function's arguments, what it does, etc? If you use the commas, you would split across several lines--not good.

Comment: Saving on typing effort will come back and hurt you later. For example, if you change `void` to `int*` it will suddenly *not* work as intended. As a rule you read code a lot more than you write it, so you should save on the effort needed to *read* the code by making it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Because declarations have this [grammar](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7):

```
declaration:
                 declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
                 static_assert-declaration
          declaration-specifiers:
                 storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
                 type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
                 type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
                 function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
                 alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
          init-declarator-list:
                  init-declarator
                  init-declarator-list , init-declarator
          init-declarator:
                  declarator
                  declarator = initializer
```

you can do it with declarations, but not with [function definitions](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html#function_definition).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//declarations
void a(void), b(void); /*OK*/

#if 0
void a() { puts("a"); }, b() { puts("b"); } /*NOPE*/
#else
//definitions
void a() { puts("a"); }
void b() { puts("b"); }
#endif
```

Comment: Would be good to point out that the originals in the question are obsolecent non-prototype declarations.